# Hibernate Criteria, Integer and "like"

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm migrating some of my hql-statements to Criterias now I'm figuring one problem:
The entity property is type Integer but I need a like with wildcards search, so in hql I do

```
session.createQuery("from P1 where id like :id").setString("id", "%"+s+"%")
```

No problem at all, Hibernate casts String to Integer.

If I try this in Criteria, I only get a ClassCastException

```
String cannot be cast to Integer

Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(P1.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.like("id",s)).addOrder(Order.asc("id")).setMaxResults(maxResults);
```

Why does Hibernate handle both situations differently?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The query engine itself is able to manage this, but the criteria engine not. Seems like there is a bug at the citeria impl.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [str expression conversion](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions). If this makes any sense.

> str() for converting numeric or
>   temporal values to a readable string

```
session.createQuery("from P1 where str(id) like :id").setString("id", "%"+s+"%")
```

This will be quite slow if you do not have a [function based index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) on the column.