# Hibernate criteria, how to add type casting?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

How to create this type of query with Hibernate criteria ?

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE CAST(price AS TEXT) LIKE '123%'
```

i have table structure like this:

```
 username(id), first_name( character varying ), safety_id(bigint)
```

and i like to select all records with safety_id like '3304%'

how do i do that ?

As Hiru correctly mentioned i was looking for bigdecimal to text casting. Also i've checked link provided by Balkrishna Rawool and that pointed me to correct way.

**Solution**

I've created NamedQuery

```
 @NamedNativeQuery(name = "getCustomerArrayForParameters", query = "SELECT * FROM view_customersflat WHERE CAST (safety_id as TEXT) LIKE :safety_id ",resultClass=Customer.class )
```

and created criteria as usual :

```
 getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("getCustomerArrayForParameters").setString("s‌​afety_id", safetyId ).list();
```

everything worked out.
Thanks for attention.

Comment: Did you tried something on your own?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859440/hibernate-cirteria-integer-and-like

Comment: i think he/she wants to cast data type to TEXT.so it's not duplicate

Comment: As Hiru correctly mentioned i was looking for bigdecimal to text casting.
Also i've checked link provided by Balkrishna Rawool and that pointed me to correct way.
 **Solution**
i've created NamedQuery

    `@NamedNativeQuery(name = "getCustomerArrayForParameters", query = "SELECT * FROM view_customersflat WHERE CAST (safety_id as TEXT)  LIKE :safety_id ",resultClass=Customer.class )`

and created criteria as usual :

`getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("getCustomerArrayForParameters").setString("safety_id", safetyId ).list();`

Comment: u can do it by criteria query but for that u have to use annotation in you pojo by making you field like @Formula("cast(price as TEXT)")    
Let me know if it's working